# How can I get telnet to auto login to this piece of equipment?

Tags: telnet, auto-login, kitty

where I work we login to a piece of equipment that has an unusual login prompt that I am not able to get Putty to recognize. Well more specifically I am using KiTTY.

The login prompt is a ASCII box in the middle of the screen. The device I am working with is an ADtran 4303 MUX.

Let's see if this works...

[image]

OK so the picture stayed formatted right. As you can see it looks odd. The only thing I trimmed off the sides was the desktop and the header which had the IP address nothing else.

How can I make KiTTY auto login to this? There is no password just a username.

Any idea?

Comment: and if you type the username and hit enter?

Comment: I get a menu that looks like its made in curses. I sadly cannot show that since it has info on it that is sensitive.